# How to Create BQL Function for Math.Ceiling or any Math class methods in Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

Looking for a Bql function to use Math Ceiling in a formula. Need help with this line in the larger example below.

```
graph.SqlDialect.scriptFunction(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal()), text, this.getTypeCodeForOperand<Operand1>(graph), text1.ToString());
```

Here is the full example I am working with.

```
public sealed class MathCeiling<Operand1> : BqlFunction, IBqlOperand, IBqlCreator
        where Operand1 : IBqlOperand
{
        private IBqlCreator a;

    public void Verify(PXCache cache, object item, List<object> pars, ref bool? result, ref object value)
    {
        value = (object)null;
        object obj1;
        if (!BqlFunction.getValue<Operand1>(ref this.a, cache, item, pars, ref result, out obj1) || obj1 == null)
            return;
        value = MathCeiling<Operand1>.calculateValue(obj1);
    }

    internal static object calculateValue(object value1)
    {
        return (object)(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(value1)));
    }

    public void Parse(PXGraph graph, List<IBqlParameter> pars, List<System.Type> tables, List<System.Type> fields, List<IBqlSortColumn> sortColumns, StringBuilder text, BqlCommand.Selection selection)
    {
        if (graph != null && text != null)
        {
            StringBuilder text1 = new StringBuilder();
            this.parseOperand<Operand1>(ref this.a, graph, pars, tables, fields, sortColumns, text1, selection);
            graph.SqlDialect.scriptFunction(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal()), text, this.getTypeCodeForOperand<Operand1>(graph), text1.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            this.parseOperand<Operand1>(ref this.a, graph, pars, tables, fields, sortColumns, text, selection);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the MathCeiling BQL Function to work by commenting out the following line: 
graph.SqlDialect.scriptFunction(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal()), text, this.getTypeCodeForOperand(graph), text1.ToString());

The MathCeiling BQL Function now works correctly